# assign shortcut key to run a script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've written a script to change the brightness of my screen.

It's useful when I am working on text mode and shortcut keys of my keyboard to change brightness doesn't work.

Is it possible to run this script, just by pressing some keys on the keyboard as shortcut, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>?

Comment: What do you mean by “on text mode”? Do you mean the text mode console (i.e. outside X Window)? On what operating system?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [xbindkeys](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbindkeys).

Your `~/.xbindkeysrc` would look something like

```
"myscript"
    Control + Alt + F7
```

Comment: This is a great answer. `xbindkeys` is awesome.

Comment: @AlexWebr, Mikel Yes, but it's for X, and I think the question is about doing this outside X.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xbindkeysrc
can you explain more?

Comment: This is a simple configuration: http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeysrc_d

Comment: I tried but it won't release the keys back to me. It acts like it still holds down Ctrl/Alt keys. I have to wait for ~5 seconds for it to release it back to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working in a terminal and don't have X running, a bit of a hack is to alias your script to a single character in your shell's configuration. Example for bash:

```
alias b='~/bin/brightness-script down'
alias B='~/bin/brightness-script up'
```

Disadvantage: you have to press `Enter` each time. Alternatively, you could do `b;b;b;b;b[Enter]` to step the brightness down 5 times.